# How to turn a dict with absolute file paths into a folder-structure-like nested Dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, filepath

I have a dict like:

```py
source_dict = {
"/a": {"foo": "bar", "randomstuff": 3},
"/b/a": {"some": "thing", "abc": {"bx": 1}},
"/b/g/h/g": {"any": "value"}
}
```

The paths could be infinite deep and they never end with `/`(> not empty 'folders' stored)

For hours I tried to get `source_dict` to a nested dict like:

```py
final_dict = {"/": {
"a": {"foo": "bar", "randomstuff": 3},
"b": {"a": {"some": "thing", "abc": {"bx": 1}}, "g": {"h": {"g": {"any": "value"}}}}
}}
```

The value not changes.
Any ideas?

Comment: your dicts are not valid python, maybe the brackets around `{"bx": 1}` should be removed?

Comment: Since you have written some code, please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @Dan Oh, I fixed the dicts, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
def group(d):
  new_d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in gb(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0][0]), key=lambda x:x[0][0])]
  return {a:b[-1][-1] if not b[0][0][1:] else group([(c, k) for [_, *c], k in b]) for a, b in new_d}

source_dict = {"/a": {"foo": "bar", "randomstuff": 3}, "/b/a": {"some":"thing", "else":{"bx": 1}}, "/b/g/h/g": {"any": "value"}}
r = {'/':group([(list(filter(None, a.split('/'))), b) for a, b in source_dict.items()])}
```

Output:

```
{'/': {'a': {'foo': 'bar', 'randomstuff': 3}, 'b': {'a': {'some': 'thing', 'else': {'bx': 1}}, 'g': {'h': {'g': {'any': 'value'}}}}}}
```